# VueJS getmethod in API is sucessful but table does not get updated after

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js

The tables are not getting populated with data but when i call {{ response }} all information in the database comes like a json string. I do not have any   errors and i can see all the data im calling as a request in the console.
This is my html table and below is my getSamples method. I am using vuejs.

```
  <div class="table-responsive">
      <base-table class="table align-items-center table-flush">
        <template slot="columns">
          <th>Species</th>
          <th>Project</th>
          <th>Theme</th>
          <th>PI</th>

        </template>

        <template slot-scope="{row}">
          <th scope="row">
            <div class="media align-items-center">
              <a href="#" class="avatar rounded-circle mr-3">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" :src="row.img"/>
              </a>
              <div class="media-body">
                <span class="name mb-0 text-sm"> Sample Data</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </th>

          <tbody>
          <tr v-for="sample in response.message" :key="sample.id">
          <td > {{sample.animal_species}} </td>

          <td > {{sample.project}} </td>

          <td > {{sample['theme.name'] }} </td>

          <td > {{sample.project_owner }} </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </template>`
     export default {
        data() {
          return {
            response: [],
          };
      },

        methods: {
          getSamples() {
            const path = 'http://localhost:5000/sample' ;
            axios.get(path)
              .then((res) => {
                this.response = res.data;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
            });
      },
      },
      created() {
        this.getSamples();
      },
```

`

Comment: Can you show console.log(res.data)?

Comment: Object { message: Getter & Setter, … }
​

Comment: Try to format the code posted here into html and JS blocks seperately for additional clarity. I am not vuejs expert, hence i am not formatting it. Please refer how to format the code snippets [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and syntax highlighting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).